# How do I use the pen tool to draw a shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

How does one create a shape in photoshop? The two ends of my shape are not closing. Can someone please tell me the principles of working with the pen tool?

Comment: Not quite sure what you question is here, what kind of things have you tried with the pen tool selected? Shapes usually close when you draw several points and then click the first point again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i was learning this helped me..Than you have to practice.
http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/photoshops-pen-tool-the-comprehensive-guide/
and then this video too.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDrtyNmp3A4

Personal Tips:
Understand what happens when you press Alt.
States: Anchor selected, drawing inside a shape or just path.
Anchor tool behaves little differently keyboard shortcut wise then if you bring it up using alt key when using pen tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think the principle you're missing is open versus closed paths. Anything drawn with the pen tool is just a path. It's not until you circle back to the origin point and click to close the path that you have a shape.

**These screen shots are old as dirt, but they're still accurate.**

This path is open but the little circle next to the pen cursor tells you that you'll close it as soon as you click. If you had a fill in this state, it would be flat across the top, essentially inventing a line between the two points.

[image]

After clicking ...

[image]

Once the shape is closed you can apply colors and effects to the object as a shape.

Smashing Magazine put together [a nice basics article on Photoshop paths](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/18/mastering-photoshop-with-paths/) you may want to skim.

If you want to dig deeper into the concept behind the pen tool in Adobe apps, read up on [Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).