# How can I change the gradient angle inside of a Live Paint object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient, drawing, illustration

I have been infatuated with this artist style of color, drawing and use of subtle textures.

http://1212m.tumblr.com/post/49348782338
[image: Look n'feel of what I'm trying to accomplish]

So I ended up drawing this derpy little thing from Final Fantasy using the pen tool in illustrator and converting it to a live paint object.
[image: Stage 1]

Ok! Making some progress here. The one issue I'm having is using the gradient illustrator with the live paint tool. I set the angle to 95 and no matter what it goes left to right as if the angle was set to 0. Any ideas as to why?

[image: No Gradient]
[image: With Gradient - left to right]

Comment: Kay, you're going to want to use Adobe Illustrator. Place this image on a layer in Illustrator, then lock it, then on a new layer use the pen tool to start tracing it. We have a lot of questions on here about the process, this one might be useful to you. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/how-do-i-use-the-pen-tool-to-draw-a-shape --- another great tutorial I recently saw is http://theagsc.com/community/tutorials/so-whats-the-big-deal-with-horizontal-vertical-bezier-handles-anyway

Comment: For the texture we have numerous questions on the topic that can probably already answer that part for you, this one appears to be a particularly useful one: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19555/how-to-apply-blend-or-overlay-a-texture-or-pattern-image-to-a-layer-in-photosho/21106#21106 ------- could also look at the texture tag for lots of other topics http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://forums.adobe.com/message/4197608#4197608

I was using the live paint bucket to fill with the gradient and attempting to interacting with the gradient tool but that was wrong.

You have to select the area in the live paint object using the "Live Paint Selection Tool"[image: Live Paint Tools]

Then you can use the gradient tool to change the angle of the gradient.